# Can't call method "context" on an undefined value

Tags: perl, catalyst

I am trying to call subroutines from one controller file to another when I am writing the following code:

Abc.pm This is the file I have the code that I need to call a subroutine to another controller file. The following subroutine I need to call.

```
package MyApp::Controller::Abc;
use Moose;
use IO::File;
use Data::Dumper;
use MyApp::MyConfig;
use MyApp::DateUtils;
use MyApp::Arrs::API;
use MyApp::Constants;
use namespace::autoclean;

sub get_token_id :Private
    {
    my $self = shift;
    my $c = $self->context;
    my $myDBI = $c->model('MyDBI')->new;
    return $myDBI->get_token_id;
    }
```

The above code I need to call to Def.pm file. Now I am calling as following:

```
package MyApp::Controller::Def;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use MyApp::Utils;

BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller'; }
my($self, $c) = @_;
my ($State, $Zip, $Country) = @_;
my $tokenid        = $self->get_token_id;
```

I am getting the following error:
**Can't call method "get_token_id" on an undefined value**

But I need to call as following only:

When I am using the following code:

```
package MyApp::Controller::Def;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use MyApp::Utils;

BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller'; }
my $self = shift;
my $c = $self->context;
my ($State, $Zip, $Country) = @_;
my $coid        = $self->get_token_id;
```

I am getting this error:
**Can't call method "context" on an undefined value**

Can any one help me why I am getting this error.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you need to `use MyApp::Controller::Def;` somewhere? I can't pick out what `$c` is an instance of, so would tend to assume something's missing in your code.

Comment: `@_` contains a sub/methods's arguments. You're accessing it when the module is loaded. Why?! Not surprisingly, it's empty, so you assign `undef` to `$self`.

Comment: More specifically: the four lines starting with `my` look like they belong in a method (which in Perl is a special kind of `sub`). You are not using them inside a `sub` at all.  Where did you find them?  You will no doubt notice that they are inside a `sub`.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause here appears to be that you're not instantiating your objects properly.

Using:

```
$self = shift;
```

is an object oriented notation, and it makes no sense if you're doing it outside a subroutine - which is what appears to be happening here. And more specifically - a subroutine that's called as a method, using `$object -> subname($some_parameter);`. If you do this, then perl passes a reference to the object as the first argument to the subroutine - which is where things like:

```
sub my_method { 
    my $self = shift;
    $self -> {some_attribute} = 1;
    $self -> some_other_method(@args);
}
```

or

```
sub some_other_method { 
    my ( $self, @args ) = @_;
    foreach ( @args ) { 
         print;
    }
}
```

type notation kicks in.

You're not doing this - you're 'shifting' in the body of a module, which will have no `@_` it's undefined, and then you're trying to call a `context` method within an undefined object. Hence the error. `get_token_id` has the same root cause.

I can't easily offer advice on how to fix it, because it's hard to be sure what you're actually trying to do. I would suggest reviewing how OO perl works though, as a refresher might be beneficial.